# How to fill viewport until all components are minimum size, then add scroll bars?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

So I have a viewport with a border layout and I'm working in the center section.
I want to add a collection of Highcharts charts, which have a minimum width/height, and also a max height.

I've created a wrapper component for each chart.

I want the chart components to be as large as possible until the center region is full, at which point they start shrinking to minimum size, at which point a scroll bar then appears.

What would the general approach be here? I have got scroll bars appearing but not the resizing.

Would a vbox with flex, and minimum heights on the chart containers, do the job?

Any advice about general approach for this type of issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can handle it with vbox layout, try to resize this window width:

[Here you can try a working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g7o)

```
Ext.create({
            xtype:'window',
            width:500,
            height:500,
            layout:{
                type:'vbox',
                align:'stretch'
            },
            scrollable:'both',
            items:[{
                xtype:'container',
                style:'background-color:red;',
                minWidth:300,
                height:200,
                margin:5
            },{
                xtype:'container',
                style:'background-color:red;',
                minWidth:300,
                height:200,
                margin:5
            },{
                xtype:'container',
                style:'background-color:red;',
                minWidth:300,
                height:200,
                margin:5
            },{
                xtype:'container',
                style:'background-color:red;',
                minWidth:300,
                height:200,
                margin:5
            }]
        }).show();
```

You need to set a minWidth to the items.

So you can set to the centered container on your border layout the vbox layout and use this example.

Answer (score 2):

You should work with minHeight (if vbox ans set align:'stretch')  and with "flex" config.

If you put flex=1, the component will stretch to fill the container, but still will respect the minHeight .

If keep adding up components they will fit the container until the min minHeight  of each one is reached and then a wild scroolbar will apear!